# Why Yii2 dateTime() functionality doens't writes the time?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, yii, yii2

I have Generated CRUD with Gii, but my migrations don't work as expected to.

```
'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
'student' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
'diploma_teacher' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
'type_of_work' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
'student_classification' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
'title' => $this->string(255)->notNull(),
'created_at' => $this->dateTime()->notNull(),
'updated_at' => $this->dateTime()->notNull(),
```

When creating new Diploma Work the field for created_at and updated_at

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you declare the `create_at` and `update_at` as follow,

```
'create_at' => $this->dateTime()->notNull()->defaultExpression('now()'),
'update_at' => $this->dateTime()->notNull()->defaultExpression('now()')->append('ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
```

Comment: Correct for MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You should add  the default value  expression

```
'created' => $this->dateTime()->notNull()->defaultExpression('now()')
```